# How to remove commits after a certain date from local branch?

Tags: git

I'm trying to test something that requires me to remove all commits after 02/14/2022. I found the commit hash `xyz` of the last commit on 02/13/2022, and did a

```
git reset --hard xyz
```

but got the error

```
fatal: failed to unpack tree object d41dc
error: Submodule 'third_party/eigen' could not be updated.
error: Submodule 'third_party/eigen' cannot checkout new HEAD.
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'xyz'.
```

I'm not sure what the `d41dc` here is. Also tried `git checkout xyz` and it gives the same error

Does anyone know how to fix this or have a better approach?

Comment: This would typically indicate a damaged repository database. Running `git fsck` may get more details on the damage, but in general most people mostly fix these by removing and re-cloning anyway, so that there's no reason to see what's actually damaged. The more important question is how the damage occurred in the first place: is your disk drive failing? Did you have a power failure while Git was updating its databases? Did you store the repository in a cloud-synced folder and have the cloud-syncing software damage it?

Answer (score 1):

Since your current local repository seems damaged, try first to re-clone in a different folder the remote repository locally.

Then apply your git reset in the new local repository.
If it works, consider renaming the existing (possible corrupted) one, and replacing it with the new (now reset) cloned repository.

Comment: hmm I just cloned a fresh copy of the repo, and still have the issue. Maybe something is wrong with remote?

Comment: @David Indeed. If the issue persists with a new clone, then the remote repository does not have your reference.